# printing theano.tensor without having any idea about the shape and type of the tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, theano

I am debugging a code which I haven't written. I want to print out `state_below_` variable which is calculated as following:

```
state_below_ = tensor.dot(state_below*emb_dropout[1], tparams[pp(prefix, 'W')]) +\
        tparams[pp(prefix, 'b')]
```

When I use `state_below_.eval()`, I get

> MissingInputError: ("An input of the graph, used to compute
>   Reshape{1}(y_sampler, TensorConstant{(1,) of -1}), was not provided
>   and not given a value.Use the Theano flag
>   exception_verbosity='high',for more information on this error.",
>   y_sampler)

error. How can I print this damn "state_below_" value?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

For evaluating and tensor, you have to pass the value of the input tensors as shown in the below code snippet.

```
import numpy
import theano.tensor as T
x = T.dscalar('x')
y = T.dscalar('y')
z = x + y
print(z.eval({x : 16.3, y : 12.1}))
```